# If $3\cos{3x} = \cos x$, then find $\frac{\sin{3x}}{\sin{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

**Question:** Given $3\cos{3x} = \cos x \neq 0$, then $\frac{\sin{3x}}{\sin{x}}$ can be written a fraction $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m + n$.

**Answer:** It is a well known fact that $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3x - 3\cos x$.

So, $12\cos^3x - 9\cos x = \cos x \Longrightarrow 12\cos^3x = 10\cos x \Longrightarrow \cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}$.

Since $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1, \sin^2x = \frac{1}{6} \Longrightarrow \sin x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}.$

It is another well known fact that $\sin{3x} = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3x.$

So, $\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin x} = 3 - 4\sin^2x = 3 - 4(\frac{1}{6}) = 3 - \frac{2}{3} = {\frac{7}{3}}.$

Reading the problem carefully, we see that we want $m + n$. So, the answer is equal to $7 + 3 = \boxed{10}$.

Please feel free to check over my solution for mistakes!

Comment: How did you go from $12\cos^3 x = 10\cos x\longrightarrow \cos x = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}$? I get $\cos^2 x = \frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: @Saegusa $12\cos^2x = 10 \Longrightarrow \cos^2x = \frac{5}{6} \Longrightarrow \cos x = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}$.

Comment: I don't understand where you possibly could have been confused. Which step seems incorrect to you?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Silly mistakes in any of my steps.

Comment: It's correct. But it's quite obviously correct.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta ok, was just making sure.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Yes then it all looks quite correct!

Comment: Is it some given information or law "It is another well known fact that $\sin{3x} = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3x.$" @Iamaperson

Comment: @JitendraSingh I was just saying that it was a well known thing.

Comment: @soupless thanks for the typo catch!

Comment: One minor quirk: When you conclude $\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{30}}6$ and $\sin x=\frac{\sqrt 6}6$, the negative values are possible as well in both cases. This does not change the result, but you should probably wirte a $\pm$ in those lines (or completely get rid of those two results, since you only need $\cos^2x$ and $\sin^2x$ for your calculations).

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht thanks for that!

Comment: A shortcut is that since $\cos^2(x) = (5/6)$, then $\sin^2(x) = (1/6)$.  As the analysis goes, the expression for $\sin(x)$ is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done one mistake (or maybe typo):

$$ 12\cos^3x = 10\cos x \implies \cos^2 x=10/12 \implies \cos x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{30}}{6}$$

Similarly, $\sin x = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}.$

Comment: Ah yes I fixed this now.

Comment: Then ya your answer is correct @Iamaperson . Same is also said by wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3cos+3x%3Dcos+x%2C+sin+%283x%29%2Fsin+x+%3D) .  Remember in wolfram alpha $-1$ is also answer but that  would be eliminated

Comment: @Iamaperson it would be eliminated because cos x is not 0

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: @Iamaperson very happy to help